# Cannot create a VSTS webhook subscription for punlisherId = tfs and eventId tfvc.checkin via the REST API

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, webhooks, tfvc, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to create a VSTS webhook subscription for publisherId= tfs and eventType= tfvc.checkin. Here's the sample Post request :

Url : https://testvstsaccount.visualstudio.com/_apis/hooks/subscriptions?api-version=1.0

Request Body :

```
{
  "publisherId": "tfs",
  "eventType": "tfvc.checkin",
  "resourceVersion": "1.0-preview.1",
  "consumerId": "webHooks",
  "consumerActionId": "httpRequest",
  "publisherInputs": {
    "path": "$/"
  },
  "consumerInputs": {
    "url": "https://myservice/myhookeventreceiver"
  }
}
```

I am getting 400 Bad Request in response.

Response body :

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "innerException": null,
  "message": "Subscription input 'path' is not supported at scope 'collection'.",
  "typeName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.WebApi.SubscriptionInputException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.WebApi, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
  "typeKey": "SubscriptionInputException",
  "errorCode": 0,
  "eventId": 4501
}
```

Can someone please help me understand the correct way to create this webhook.

Comment: I have also tried the following request url : https://testvstsaccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/hooks/subscriptions?api-version=1.0 . I get the same error.

Comment: Shouldn't it contain 'DefaultCollection' in the URL? Like this:  https://testvstsaccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/hooks/subscriptions?api-version=1.0

Comment: @YanSklyarenko : You are right. I tried that as well. As mentioned in my previous comment, i tried that as well.

Comment: Looks like it complains about 'path' property, but I can't find the 'path' property in the sample JSON request here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/hooks/subscriptions#create-a-subscription.

Comment: The sample listed at this link offers publisherInputs for eventType: build.complete. Infact, I get the following error when I used the sample for eventType : tfvc.checkin. The error message says :  "message": "Unknown subscription input \"branch\" for publisher \"Team Foundation Server\" and event type \"Code checked in\".".
I got the required inputDescriptors for eventType:tfvc.checkin by using api : "https://testvstsaccount.visualstudio.com/_apis/hooks/publishers/tfs?api-version=1.0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `path` is filtering to checkins that change one or more files under the specified path. It should look like `$/TeamProject`, or `$/TeamProject/Project`, or `$/TeamProject/Project/...`. `$/` is not supported. Check my example below:

```
POST https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/hooks/subscriptions?api-version=1.0

Content-Type: application/json

{
  "consumerActionId": "httpRequest",
  "consumerId": "webHooks",
  "consumerInputs": { "url": "https://xxx.visualstudio.com" },
  "eventType": "tfvc.checkin",
  "publisherId": "tfs",
  "publisherInputs": {
    "path": "$/TestCase/TestCaseProject",
    "projectId": "1decf66b-1974-43e3-xxxx-ba9a3fd2xxxx"
  },
  "resourceVersion": "1.0",
  "scope": 1
}
```